# Bike Frame Brand and Model?

Tags: frames

[image][image]enter image description here[image]I purchased this bike at a thrift shop and it rides like a dream.  Out of curiosity I'm trying to figure out the make and brand.  The parts on it seem to be very nice so I'm thinking that the frame is top of the line too.  your help is much appreciated.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks pretty generic to me. Do you have any evidence of the parts being nice? Look for a serial number on the head thube or near the bottom bracket or near the dropouts.

Comment: It has an all city crank, dura Ace hubs, custom red paint.